# URL is mapped but no mapping found by MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I found several issues like this, but non of them are helping.

I am trying to write integration test based on [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring). It looks like that the context is configured well, urls are mapped:

> 2017-11-20 11:14:58 INFO  main RequestMappingHandlerMapping:537 - Mapped "{[/ || /index],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.ge.med.serviceability.agentserver.web.WebpagesController.index()

but I get a 404 error in my test:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Also in my server log:

> 2017-11-20 11:15:02 WARN  main PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/index] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

**UPDATE:** I don't know if this is normal or not but DispatcherServlet is registered with the name "dispatcher-servlet"

```
DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet( webappCtx );
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder( "dispatcher-servlet", servlet );
```

But in the error log the servlet does not have any name.

The config is a bit complex for some reasons but here is:
My test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(
  classes = { AppConfig.class },
  loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class
)
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WorkstationRestControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup( )
        throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( wac ).build( );
  }

  @Test
  public void controllerBeanTest( )
        throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform( get( "/index" ) ).andExpect( status( ).isOk( ) );
  }
```

AppConfig.java:

```
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = {
      "com.ge.med.serviceability.agentserver",
      "com.ge.med.serviceability.common"
    },
  excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter( Controller.class ) }
)
@Configuration
@Import(
  {
    JettyConfig.class,
    DbConfig.class
  }
)
public class AppConfig {
```

JettyConfig registers MvcConfig:

```
  @Bean
  public ServletHolder dispatcherServletHolder( ) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webappCtx =
      new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext( );
    webappCtx.setParent( applicationContext );
    webappCtx.register( MvcConfig.class );
    webappCtx.register( PublicServicesConfig.class );

    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet( webappCtx );
    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder( "dispatcher-servlet", servlet );
    holder.setInitOrder( 1 );
    holder.setInitParameter( "dispatchOptionsRequest", "true" );
    holder.setAsyncSupported( true );

    return holder;
  }
```

MvcConfig.java:

```
@ComponentScan(
  useDefaultFilters = false,
  basePackages = { "com.ge.med.serviceability.agentserver.web" },
  includeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter( Controller.class ) }
)
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(
  {
    SecurityConfig.class,
    WebSocketConfig.class
  }
)
public class MvcConfig
      extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
      implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

WebpagesController.java:

```
@Controller
public class WebpagesController {

  @Autowired
  SimpMessagingTemplate template;

  @Autowired
  WebSocketPushService wsPushService;

  @RequestMapping( "/login.html" )
  public String login( ) {
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping( "/403.html" )
  public String notAuthorized( ) {
    return "403";
  }

  @RequestMapping( "/login-error.html" )
  public String loginError( Model model ) {
    model.addAttribute( "loginError", true );
    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(
    value = {
        "/",
        "/index"
      },
    method = RequestMethod.GET
  )
  public ModelAndView index( ) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView( );
    model.setViewName( "index" );
    return model;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init( ) {
    wsPushService.setMessagingTemplate( template );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that for your test to work, you need to tell MockMvc which controller you are going to test by doing this : MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(__yourController__).build(); . It will help you build your test in an easier way

Comment: Hi, I tried with this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup( new WebpagesController( ) ).build( ); and the issue is the same. Thx

Comment: I also think you annotation is wrong. You should try to replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`. And you should never do a `new` call on a Spring bean wuch as you did, as it won't be properly instantiated.